# Instead of java script why can't we use perl script?

Tags: perl

I need explanation of Perl script why didn't using in web pages as java script?
    What different between two script, can any one explain this?

I want something write to in web pages by Perl script,
am not mean CGI script,  Perl script , 
because why I asking this questions, Perl simplest method using in there.

suppose we can't work with Perl script... Why?

Can you please explain briefly?.......

Java script:

```
 <script language="JScript"> </script>
```

can you explain... in Perl

Comment: Because no browsers support it (short of maybe old versions of IE) and never will on accounts of Perl not having anywhere near the stringent sandboxing support needed.

Comment: "can you explain... in Perl" I'm looking forward to someone answering this question, in Perl.

Comment: thank you to all very well explanation.... thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can only execute client side code if the browser can pass that code off to a suitable interpretor or compiler.

The only Perl engine supported by browsers was ActiveState's PerlScript which was IE/Windows only, required a plug-in to be installed, and (as far as I know) has been discontinued.

In short: You can't use Perl client side because browser vendors haven't done the work needed to support Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Perl is just not embedded into web browser, so there's no way to get a Perl script on client side for that very simple reason...